# Updating a collection to db

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, nhibernate

This may be a little naive but I just want check my way of doing this is correct.
I receive a collection of objects from the UI.
I then wish to check those objects against the records in the db.

This is what I am doing to  Create Update and Delete the received objects.

1. Loop trough received objects - if
   (id == 0 ) create new record.
2. Retrieve existing records from db;
3. Loop existing records - Where
   (existing record id == recieved
   object id) Update record.
4. If the
   record exists in the existing
   records but not in the received
   objects - Delete.

This seems the most logical way to do this. I am using NHibernate and was kind of wondering whether there was another way I should be looking into.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take my answer for what it's worth; I say that your logic is solid.

Answer (score 0):

If you do use SQL Server 2008 (or could opt to use it), there's a new "MERGE" statement that basically does all that.

In that case, you could write all your data into a temporary table (in memory or on disk), and then update and insert your data into the target table with a single MERGE statement.

Here are some info posts on SQL Server 2008's MERGE:

- [SQL Server 2008 - The Power of Merge](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/3122/) (requires free registration)
- [SQL Server 2008 MERGE](http://blogs.conchango.com/davidportas/archive/2007/11/14/SQL-Server-2008-MERGE.aspx)
- [Using SQL Server 2008's MERGE statement](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/sqlserver/soa/Using-SQL-Server-2008-s-MERGE-statement/0,339028455,339283059,00.htm)
- [SQL Server 2008 Merge Statement](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/SQL_Server_2008_MERGE_Statement_p1.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008 - Intro to MERGE](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/)